# Apache and ECC Curve Order

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, ssl, openssl

I have Ubuntu 15.04 with Apache 2.4.10 (OpenSSL 1.0.1f) and I would like to configure Apache SSL.conf specifically for "ECC Curve Order" as on Windows 10, where I select the preferred order of Elliptic Curves. I have two questions related to this:

1) On OpenSSL, how do I view the supported ECC Curves of my system?

2) On Apache, how do I configure (inside ssl.conf) the curve order? Can I also set it to follow a specific preference order? (1st P-521, 2st P-384, 3rd P-256)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a bit late for an answer… but:

For the 1st question, use:

```
openssl ecparam -list_curves
```

For the second question, SSLOpenSSLConfCmd should do the job, but I don't if it will work with your version.

```
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Curves P-521:P-384
```

An other way, from the Apache doc:

> Custom DH parameters and an EC curve name for ephemeral keys, can also
>   be added to end of the first file configured using SSLCertificateFile.
>   This is supported in version 2.4.7 or later. Such parameters can be
>   generated using the commands openssl dhparam and openssl ecparam. The
>   parameters can be added as-is to the end of the first certificate
>   file. Only the first file can be used for custom parameters, as they
>   are applied independently of the authentication algorithm type.